# Mostrar Post pertenecientes a una categoria de un CPT

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Muy buenas,
Quisiera saber como hacer mediante programación o mediante un plugin lo siguiente:

- Tengo un custom post type (CPT) llamado producto, y estos "productos" se agrupan en categorias (p.ej. Magdalenas, croissants, etc...).
- Entonces quiero fabricar los enlaces que me muestren todos los productos asociados a las diferentes categorias: un enlace para mostrar todas las magdalenas, otro para mostrar todos los croissants, etc...

Adicionalmente, las categorías están jerarquizadas y un producto puede pertenecer a varias categorías.
Adicionalmente también, no es una tienda Woocommerce, con lo cual no puede venir la solución por ahí.

Sé que puede ser una pregunta muy básica pero no consigo dar con la forma de mostrar los productos y sin eso, el CPT que he creado, no sirve para nada.

Gracias por vuestro interés, y a ver si entre todos damos con la respuesta.

Comment: las categorías son también un "custom taxonomy" ?

Comment: categorías es una taxonomía nativa según el plugin CPTUI.
Es decir las categorías son exclusivas de los post tipo Producto.
Por lo tanto yo diría que sí son custom taxonomies

Comment: page builder ( onda elementor ) o child-theme ?

Comment: elementor con child theme de Mynote (Versión: 1.4.0)

Comment: con elementor pro podes generar un template de tipo archive y asignárselo tanto al listado de CPT como al listado de CPT x custom Taxonomy, si el cpt es "productos" y la custom tax es "productos-por-marca" ambos slugs te listan los productos. para hacer un árbol de categorias custom ahi hay que extender el widget o meter un shortcode

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución:
 - Crear una plantilla y programar el loop con este código:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: nombre_de_la_plantilla
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
           $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'producto',
        'cat' => 43,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 50,
        );
   $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

   if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
      while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
         $category_posts->the_post();
?>
         <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
         <div class='post-content'><?php the_content() ?></div>    
<?php
      endwhile;
   else: 
?>
      Vaya, no hay entradas.
<?php
   endif;
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

el numero 43 es el id de la categoria y "producto" es el post type

Comment: si es un template para página y no un archive-CPT.php te faltaría agregarle el paginado: `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
` al principio y `'paged' => $paged,` en los args, o directamente `'posts_per_page' => -1,` para que traiga todos pero a futuro puede dejar medio pesado el asunto